# Render issue when print html page using Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

Here is the simple HTML and style I used:

```html
    <div class="p1">
        <h1>First Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="p2">
        <h1>Second Title</h1>
    </div>
```

```css
        .p1 {
            width: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 860px;
        }
        .p2 {
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: 1px dashed black;
        }
```

When I open the page in the Chrome browser, everything is fine:

[image]

However, when I try to save it as PDF by using Chrome print functionality layout changed, it seems the first paragraph and the second paragraph overlapped:

[image]

Why this happened and how can I solve this issue?

Here is the demo online: https://codepen.io/hh54188/pen/LYBpBKq

Comment: there's a reason why did you choose `display: inline-block`? did you try to change it as `display: block;` (or just leave it unset so that it will default as that)? that's all the html/css you have in that page?

Comment: Removing `display: inline-block;` will indeed fix the issue. So if you don't need it, this would be the easy fix